# Как реализованы базовые типы в C#?

Tags: c#, double, структуры

Для упрощения некоторых аспектов предстоящих разработок, пишу небольшую библиотеку. Требуется несколько расширить тип `double` - добавить несколько методов. Посмотрел, как объявлен этот тип в `.NET`, оказалось, что это структура, наследующая несколько интерфейсов. Первая мысль - попытаться унаследовать эту структуру, но в C# структуры могут наследовать только интерфейсы. Тогда я в своей структуре реализовал все интерфейсы, которые есть в `double:  IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable<double>, IEquatable<double>`. Теперь моя структура должна была стать клоном `double`, но этого не произошло. Я не могу напрямую присвоить значение этой структуре, то есть не могу написать так

```
MyDouble a = 20;
```

Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Требуется несколько расширить тип double - добавить несколько методов

Для этого существуют [методы-расширения (*Extension Methods*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: Да, спасибо, метод подходит для решения моей задачи. Но вопрос остаётся открытым: что происходит в недрах double при присваивании?

Comment: Там происходит неявное преобразование int в double. Реализуется таким образом:

    public static implicit operator double(int that)
    {
        return (double)that;
    }

Comment: А поля таким образом можно добавить?

Comment: Нет, только методы.

Comment: А почему в этом случае нельзя использовать переопределение оператора присвоения?

    MyDouble a = 20;

Comment: Оператор присвоения не перегружается в C#.

Answer (score 3):

В .NET структуры наследуются от System.ValueType, а ValueType - от System.Object. Насколько я помню, наследование структур запрещено из-за выделения памяти.

Например:

```
struct A{
    int a;
}

struct B : A{
    int b;
}
```

Тогда для структуры B нужно будет выделить в 2 раза больше памяти, следовательно при таких вещах, как:

```
A _a = new B();
```

Соответственно, поскольку структуры хранятся в стеке, некая неизвестная часть стека должна быть переписана => exception.

Comment: Откуда вы это помните? В том же C++ наследование не запрещено, наследников присваивают родителям и ничего не падает.

Comment: @Flammable: проблема в том, что при 

    A _a = new B();

в переменной _a будет экземпляр `A`, а не `B`. То есть, информация будет потеряна. А весь C# ведёт себя не так:

    string s = "Test";
    object o = s;
    string restored = (string)o; // информация восстановлена

То есть у C# есть reference conversion, но не value conversion.

Value conversion тоже иногда бывает, но для этого нужен явный cast и оператор конверсии у типа:

    long l = long.MaxValue;
    int i = (int)l;

Comment: Нет, давайте рассматривать конкретно value-типы, раз уж о них речь.

> проблема в том, что ...

Это вовсе не проблема. Как вы уже заметили, никто ведь не называет проблемой преобразование long -> int и обратно?
[Здесь][1], например, считают, что наследование структур запрещено из-за не вполне очевидного способа прострелить себе ногу при обходе массивов (который, кстати, [доступен и в С++][2]).

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222935/why-dont-structs-support-inheritance

  [2]: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/array-derived-vs-base.html